# How do the radius and the center of the circular orbits of a particle depend on an adiabatically changing $B$ field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, orbital-motion, invariants

Preparing for a classical mechanics qual exam with my CM final from last semester.

Problem:

> Consider the circular orbits in the $xy$ plane with $x > 0$ of a particle
> mass $m$ and charge $q$ in a constant and uniform magnetic field $B$ in the
> $z$ direction. (This magnetic field could be created by a sheet of
> current in the $yz$ plane at $x = 0$ as shown below.)

[image]

First part of the problem I understand completely after seeing my professor's provided solution. It reads:

> Use the Hamiltonian formulation to determine the radius and angular
> frequency of the circular orbits. Relate the center of the circular
> orbit to the canonical momenta of the problem. Use the gauge $A =
> B(0,x,0)$ and the define the cyclotron frequency, $ωB = qB/m$ (I'm using
> SI units).

However I can only get so far in the second part of the problem which involves adiabatic invariants:

> Now imagine that starting at $t = 0$ the strength of the magnetic field
> is slowly increased from its initial value of $B_0 ≡ B(0)$. If the
> original orbit has radius $r_0$ and is centered at $x_0 = (x_0,0,0)$ with $x_0 \gg 0$, determine how the radius and the center of the circular orbits change as $B(t)$ is slowly increased. Describe your results qualitatively by drawing a sketch.

My progress thus far is the following:

the adiabatic invariant reads $I=\frac{1}{2} \iint dq dp =\frac{1}{2} \cdot$ phase space area

To find the phase space area I consider the following:
if the energy of the orbit purely kinetic, we would find $\epsilon=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ such that my semi major axis for momentum of the phase space ellipse would be $p_0=\sqrt{2m\epsilon}$.

If the energy of the orbit purely potential, we would find $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}m \omega_{B}^2 r^2$ such that my semi major axis for position of the phase space ellipse would be $r_0=\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon}{m \omega_{B}^2}}$.

So then my adiabatic invariant is $I=\frac{\epsilon}{\omega_B}$, or rewritting for $\epsilon$ and plugging that into my radius formula,

$$
r_0=\sqrt{\frac{2 I}{m \omega_B}}
$$

which can be generalized by realizing the adiabatic invariant is depependent on energy and the adiabatic parameter varied (in my case $B(t)$). thus

$$
r(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2 I}{m \omega_B}}
$$

I am stuck on the final steps my professor takes in his solution:

[image]

The other part of equation 27 I got from the first part of the problem no problem, but everything below that is completely foreign to me! Can anyone help explain what equation 28 means/where it comes from, as well as how equation 29 for the "constant flux" was arrived at?